# Json.Net code stopped working

Tags: c#, json.net

I have a routine that takes a JSON packet and drops it to a dynamic c# variable:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
...
dynamic Work = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Result);
string OrganizationID = Work.idOrganizations[0].ToString();
```

It has worked for months until this week, suddenly it stopped (Json.Net 7.0.1).  When I try to reference idOrganizations in the last line (which does indeed exist in the children, verified in QuickWatch) it fails with:

```
{"'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' does not contain a definition for 'idOrganizations'"}
```

Here is a snippet of the JSON:

```
{"id":"...","idOrganizations":["..."],"loginTypes":null}
```

I know I can use Work["idOrganizations"]... but I would have to make the similar change in many lines of code.

Did something change in Json.Net, or was this an incorrect construct from the beginning that just happened to work until now?

Comment: Show the example JSON string. By the way, you are not trying to reference `idOrganizations` like you stated. You are trying to access `idOrganzations`. Note the different spellings.

Comment: Thanks for catching that, was a typo in the question, but the problem remains after checking the code for correct spelling.  Here is a snippet of the JSON:
    {"id":"...","idOrganizations":["..."],"loginTypes":null,...}

Comment: You should update your question to fix the typo and also add the Json snippit.

Comment: Please update your JSON snippets so that it's [minimal and complete](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Providing an invalid JSON string that doesn't give us a proper overview of the structure isn't that useful.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem.  See https://dotnetfiddle.net/6LyfRc

Comment: are you 100% sure that `idOrganizations` is included in ALL messages that you receive?

Comment: jgauffin: Yes, it is a core field in the Trello API.
dbc: Based on your dotnetfiddle, I noticed even thought you selected Json..Net 7.0.1, the version displayed was 6.  So I downgraded to 6.0.8 via NuGet, and everything works perfectly again.